# OnSuccess from Ajax.BeginForm in PartialView not fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've got a page with a button to display a modal Partial View with a form. When submitting the form, all is going well on the server side, but the OnSuccess event is not fired.

**My View**

```
<button id="btnAddLine" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newOperation">Add Operation</button>
<div id="newOperation" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent"></div>
   </div>
</div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script>
            var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayAddOperation")';
            $('#btnAddLine').click(function () {
                $('#myModalContent').load(url, function () {
                    $('#newOperation').modal('show');
                });
            })

            var onSubmitSuccess = function (result) {
                if (!result.success) {
                    $('#newOperation').html(result);
                } else {
                    alert('thanks for submitting');
                    $('#newOperation').dialog('close');
                }
            };
        </script>
    }
```

**My Partial View**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4>
        Stock
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </h4>
</div>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddOperation", 
    "ManagePortfolio", 
    null, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = @"onSubmitSuccess" }, 
    new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="modal-body">
    ......
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**The Controller**

```
  // GET: ManagePortfolio
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     List<Stock> stocks = db.Stocks.Include("Description").ToList();         
     return View(stocks);
  }

  // GET: AddOperation
  public ActionResult DisplayAddOperation()
  {
     return PartialView("AddOperation");
  }

  // POST: AddOperation
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AddOperation()
  {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Operation Added !!!!!");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Can't find that");
  }
```

As often pointed out, the unobtrusive script is loaded.
I also tried to simply display an alert for the OnSuccess event, something like `OnSuccess = "alert('yeah!')"` but not more successful.

Comment: have you included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` ?? Its need for `Ajax.BeginForm`

Comment: Arrrrgh !!! I've included jquery.validate.unobtrusive but not the ajax script !!! Sorry